# Javascript Object Literals for property with method

Tags: javascript

```js
const products = [
        {
            id: 5,
            productName: "Logitech Mouse",
            unitprice: 35
        },
        {
            id: 6,
            productName: "Logitech Keyboard",
            unitprice: 40
        }
    ];

    const carts = [
        {
            id: 101,
            userId: 3,
            productId: 5,
            quantity: 2,
            total: function () {
                 return this.unitprice * this.quantity             
            }
        }        
    ];

    let joined = carts.map(item => {
        console.log(item.total);
        let { id, ...rest } = products.find(p => p.id === item.productId);
        debugger
        return {
            ...rest, 'quantity': item.quantity,
            'total': item.total
        };
    });
    console.log(joined);
```

How do I get the total property for the new object at the end? I tried with the above but the total value 10 is not there. I tried another version at below but still no success.

```
get total() {
            return this.unitprice * this.quantity
        }
```

Comment: can you explain  your expected result

Comment: Indeed. The `.map` method returns an array, so... what are you trying to do here?

Comment: trying to get the `total` (unit price * quantity) into new object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A getter would work, the only issue is, it won't have access to the unit price. You will have to pass through the unit price.

```js
const products = [{
    id: 5,
    productName: "Logitech Mouse",
    unitprice: 35
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    productName: "Logitech Keyboard",
    unitprice: 40
  }
];

const carts = [{
  id: 101,
  userId: 3,
  productId: 5,
  quantity: 2,
  total: function(unitprice) {
    return unitprice * this.quantity
  }
}];

let joined = carts.map(item => {
  let {
    id,
    unitprice,
    ...rest
  } = products.find(p => p.id === item.productId);
  debugger
  return {
    ...rest,
    'quantity': item.quantity,
    'total': item.total(unitprice)
  };
});
console.log(joined);
```

Comment: for ` 'total': item.total(unitprice)`, do we need  'total': item.total(item.unitprice)`?

Comment: the `unitprice` comes from the product, and it's deconstructed above. Item does not have `unitprice`;

Answer (score 1):

u can try:

```js
const products = [
  {
    id: 5,
    productName: "Logitech Mouse",
    unitprice: 35
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    productName: "Logitech Keyboard",
    unitprice: 40
  }
];

const carts = [
  {
    id: 101,
    userId: 3,
    productId: 5,
    quantity: 2,
    total: function () {
      return products.find(product => product.id === this.productId).unitprice * this.quantity;
    }
  }
];

let joined = carts.map(item => {
  console.log(item.total());
  let { id, ...rest } = products.find(p => p.id === item.productId);

  return {
    ...rest, "quantity": item.quantity,
    "total": item.total
  };
});
console.log(joined);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let joined =  carts.filter((ca)=>{
    return products.some((c)=>{
       //place your exact calculations here(c.id === ca.productId)
       // ca.total = -- your result
       return c;
       })
    });
```

Try this way.